# Spring Data + MySql - Referencing non-existant record. Phantom records?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, relational-database

I have a Java Spring application backed by MySql. I have Users (UserEntity) and Lawfirms (LawfirmEntity). I also have a bunch of APIs to access my data. Because I use Spring Data, loading one entity may lead to related entities being loaded.

When I hit my API that's supposed to fetch all lawfirms (i.e. GET /v1/lawfirms), I get the following error:

```
Unable to find UserEntity with id 108; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException
```

Well no kidding, I don't have a User with ID 108 in my Users table! So I figured there was another record somewhere referencing a user with ID 108, but as it turns out, I do not. Where is Spring picking up this user Id 108 from?? Does MySql sometimes cache deleted records?

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: How are you retrieving your `UserEntity`? Can you please update your post with that info?

Comment: Does the `LawFirmsEntity` table has a reference to `UserEntity` but no foreign key between the two tables?

Comment: You deleted `User`, but `Lawfirm` still has reference for this user. To prevent such database states, you have to create foreign-key constraint between this two tables, and set action of this constraint - `restricted`